# Can we debug the APK with ASAN active on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, address-sanitizer

My project is a simple game with native C++ code and Java, which uses cmake to compile C/C++ code. I'm using address sanitizer to check my the code. I follow the instruction [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/asan)

My OS is windows 10 64bit.

However, when I press debug on Android Studio, I got the message as

```
2020-03-19 13:50:56.946 5152-5152/? E/logwrapper: executing /data/app/com.indie.haiphan.Breakout-ZFFz_f8ETleajrgP6rg9gw==/lib/arm64/wrap.sh failed: No such file or directory
2020-03-19 13:50:56.946 5151-5151/? I/wrap.sh: executing /data/app/com.indie.haiphan.Breakout-ZFFz_f8ETleajrgP6rg9gw==/lib/arm64/wrap.sh failed: No such file or directory
2020-03-19 13:50:56.956 5151-5151/? I/wrap.sh: wrap.sh terminated by exit(255)
2020-03-19 13:50:56.957 873-873/? W/Zygote: Error reading pid from wrapped process, child may have died
```

I checked on my APK (with Analyze APK of Android Studio) the wrap.sh exist.
So my question is I can't debug with wrap.sh inside the APK?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have BOM or an extra carriage return at the end of the first line of your `wrap.sh`. Which *is* possible in windows.

To fix it you can use `dos2unix` tool.

See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27067/197738

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I follow it and the error `missing wrap.sh` disappear, however, I still can not debugging my app.

Comment: @seal2002 This is a separate question, so I would recommend asking a new one :-)

Comment: Yeah, It is better if separate it. I will do it

Comment: This saved me! Our problem was that we generated the script from gradle/groovy. On Windows groovy BufferedWriter.writeLine created the script with Windows style line endings but the script is run from Android so it didn't like it. When building from e.g. Linux this work fine but generating the script from a Windows machine failed.